# C++ - Passing rvalue references to function?

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble understanding how rvalue references work. I have the following code:

```
void f(int&& i)
{}

int main()
{
    int i = 42;
    int&& r = std::move(i);

    f(r);

    return 0;
}
```

Here, I'm getting the following compiler error:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:46:7: error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘int&&’ to lvalue of type ‘int’
     f(r);
       ^
prog.cpp:38:6: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void f(int&&)’
 void f(int&& i)
      ^
```

Why does the compiler think I'm passing an lvalue, when I explicitly declared `r` to be an rvalue reference? Doing `f(std::move(r))` seems to work, but I still don't understand what's different there.

Is this because, in the `f(r)` call, `r` is taken to be an lvalue? If so, what's the type of `std::move(r)`?

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but possibly has (some of) the answers you seek: [What is std::move(), and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413470/what-is-stdmove-and-when-should-it-be-used)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lvalue to rvalue reference binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583531/lvalue-to-rvalue-reference-binding)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Types and [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) are two different things.

(emphasis mine)

> Each C++ expression (an operator with its operands, a literal, a variable name, etc.) is characterized by **two independent properties: a type and a value category**.

As a named variable, `r` is an lvalue, which can't be bound to rvalue-reference.

(emphasis mine)

> The following expressions are lvalue expressions:
>
> - the name of a variable, a function, a template parameter object (since C++20), or a data member, regardless of type, such as `std::cin`
>     or `std::endl`. **Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the
>     expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression**;

On the other hand, `std::move(r)` is an [xvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#xvalue), which is a kind of rvalue and could be bound to rvalue-reference.

> The following expressions are xvalue expressions:
>
> - a function call or an overloaded operator expression, whose return type is rvalue reference to object, such as `std::move(x)`;

About your doubt,

> Is this because, in the `f(r)` call, `r` is taken to be an lvalue? If so, what's the type of `std::move(r)`?

Yes, `r` is an lvalue expression, and `std::move(r)` is an xvalue (rvalue) expression; even both the type is rvalue-reference, i.e. `int&&`.

Comment: Makes sense. Funny that something as conceptually simple as passing a thing to a function to work with is so ungodly complex in C++.

Comment: @Martin This is quite C++-style thinking... ;)